# How to attach to container logs in vscode from terminal

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have been playing around with vscode's Dev Container extension and the customizable `.devcontainer.json` file. I am able to successfully build and attach to the specified running container, however I am trying to find an easier way to configure my work space to attach to the container's logs. I can do this via the Remote Explorer:

`Containers` -> `Dev Containers` -> `{Container}` -> `Show Container Log`

This will launch a new terminal window with the attached container logs. Is there a way to do this from the terminal? Can it be done via `settings.json` in `.vscode/`? Ideally I'd like to have this terminal (split with bash then the logs) be open on vscode launch. Attached is a picture of what I am trying to achieve automatically. Thanks to all of those who respond in advance.[image]

Comment: Have u tried to use persistent-sessions https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_persistent-sessions ?

Answer (score 1):

The command to run is `docker logs --tail 1000 -f [CONTAINER_ID]`, where `--tail 1000` shows the last 1000 lines in the log, `-f` follows the log output, and `[CONTAINER_ID]` is the ID of the container (that can be found via a `docker ps`)

Alternatively, you can drag the Terminal entry around the UI.

For example, on the far right (in your sample image) where it says "backend web", you can drag that around.

Using the docker extension, you right click the process you want to view and click "View logs" as normal, then on the far right drag the new terminal into another terminal, or anywhere else in the UI

Comment: I guess it is not working as the terminal session runs within the container. As long as the docker socket does not get mounted into the container, the logs shouldn't be accessible that way.